# Как удалить фото в django-ckeditor?

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

я пытаюсь поставить себе в админ панель ckeditor в django .
У меня возник вопрос ,как можно удалить фото при редактировании его в ckeditor.

Например у меня есть статья с фотками и надо сделать так ,если я удалил из статьи фото , чтобы фото удалялось из папки в которой она храниться, чтобы не засорять фотками.

Ниже предоставлен весь код

настройки ckeditor

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'news_image/'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_SLUGIFY_FILENAME = False

CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js'
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
        'height': 300,
        'width': '100%',
        'extraPlugins': ','.join([
            'uploadimage',
            'image2',
            'codesnippet',
        ]),
        'filebrowserBrowseUrl': '/ckeditor/browse/',
        'filebrowserUploadUrl': '/ckeditor/upload/',
        'filebrowserImageBrowseUrl': '/ckeditor/browse/',

        'filebrowserImageUploadUrl': '/ckeditor/upload/',
        'uploadUrl': '/ckeditor/upload/',
    },
}
```

форма

```
class NewsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorUploadingWidget())

    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = ('name', 'content')
```

сама моделька

```
class News(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Название")
    content = RichTextField(config_name="default" , verbose_name="Контент" , default="")
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Дата создания")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Добавить новость"
        verbose_name_plural = "Добавить новости"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```